# Different positioning on iOS7 iPad Mini and iOS6 iPad 3

Tags: ipad, ios6, ios7, uilabel

I have a simple placement of a UILabel in my app's code:

```
headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 884, 68)];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HoboStd" size:64];
headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[self.view addSubview:gameSpeaks];
```

On an iOS6 iPad 3 the text is showing a little higher up on the screen than it is on the iOS 7 iPad Mini with the same code, same .xib and everything. Does anybody know if this is a result of iOS6 vs iOS7 or if it is a result of the different devices or some other issue I am not aware of?

I *WANT* to say that the iPad Mini was showing the text in the same position as the iPad 3 when I was testing with it on iOS6, and then I upgraded it to iOS7 and noticed this difference. If it is the OS version that is causing this issue - what is the preferred way for testing for OS version in code so that I can reposition the label as needed when running on an OS7 device vs OS6?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

It's a result of `iOS6` vs `iOS7` given that the status bar is now part of the view.

In `iOS7`, everything will appear about 20 pixels farther up than it did in `iOS6` and previous if you do not adjust them.

In `iOS6` and previous, setting a UI element's y origin to `0` would put it at the very bottom edge of the status bar.  In `iOS7`, a y origin of `0` will now put it at the very top edge of the screen, behind the (now transparent) status bar.

You can get the current version of a device using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```